# how to insert array in numpy using two variables

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

if I have array:
a=[1,2,3]
b=[7,8,9]
I want to get new array c=[1,7,2,8,3,9], which is alternating arrangement between a and b. How to use np.insert on that case?

Answer (score 1):

```
# solution 1
import numpy as np
a=[1, 2, 3]
b=[7, 8, 9]
list(np.transpose((a,b)).flatten())
# output [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9]

# solution 2
import operator
a=[1, 2, 3]
b=[7, 8, 9]
reduce(operator.concat, map(lambda x, y : [x, y], a, b))
# output [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].